# Xcode: The executable was signed with invalid entitlements

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode10, entitlements, code-signing-entitlements

When compiling an application in Xcode I run into this non-specific error:

> The executable was signed with invalid entitlements.
>
> The entitlements specified in your application's Code Signing
>   Entitlements file are invalid, not permitted, or do not match those
>   specified in your provisioning profile. (0xE8008016)

Some answers suggest removing the Entitlements file, but the app uses Push Notifications and it seems to be required for use of that feature.

The file was auto-generated by Xcode from Capabilities tab.

The `AppName.entitlements` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>development</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The provisioning profile has 6 entitlements:

[image: entitlements enabled in the provisioning profile]

Might be Xcode version related, prior to update to 10.3 it worked.